# Can we use dependency version range for maven plugins?

Tags: maven

When I use version range for dependencies, it works fine but the same range for plugins fails.

So I have my own plugin, say:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mytest</groupId>
        <artifactId>mytest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>[1.0.0, 2.0.0)</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This works like a charm, however, the following won't work:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.mytest</groupId>
        <artifactId>mytest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>[1.0.0, 2.0.0)</version>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And I get error saying could not find prefix "mytest". If I change the version in plugin section to 1.0.1, things are fine. I was wondering if ranges won't work for plugins or I am missing something here?

Comment: For plugins you can't use ranges cause it does not make sense...Apart from that a dependency should never contain a plugin...

Comment: Aw yes, I added that as dependency only to test if version range works. So we can't have version range for maven plugins! But why it doesn't make sense? Isn't this similar to SNAPSHOT version where maven picks the latest revision?